# Dynamic checkbox within accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I'm dynamically populating data into a jQuery accordion. I need to have a checkbox just before the `<h2>` text.

```
<div id="checkbox">
  <h2>
    <span>
       <input type="checkbox" class="mycheck" value="apple" />
    </span>
    Text 1
  </h2>
  <div> content 1 </div>
</div>
```

My question is, When I click on the checkbox the accordion expands and the checkbox isn't getting checked. How do I make the checked mark to appear and prevent the accordion from expanding when clicked on the checkbox?

```
$("#accordianParent").accordion({
      collapsible: true,active: false
});

$(document).on('click', '.mycheck', function(ev){ 
        ev.stopPropagation(); 
        console.log("clicked!");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

the accordion seems to prevent default on your checkbox when using it inside the Element.

You can use the activate/beforeactivate Event to check it manually:

```
$("#accordianParent").accordion({
    collapsible: true,active: false,

    beforeActivate: function( event, ui ) {
       var checked = ui.newHeader.length ? true : false;
       $(event.currentTarget).find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', checked);
    }

});
$(document).on('click', '.mycheck', function(ev){
    ev.stopPropagation();
    console.log("clicked!");
});
```